# Time Machine stopped working after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: time-machine, macbook-pro, macos

[image]

I have upgraded my Mountain Lion system to the latest Yosemite release in the App Store.

When I click the `Back Up Now` link in the Time Machine menu it says it's preparing the backup but it never gets past this and actually starts backing the system up.

How do I get Time Machine working again?

Comment: thanks @Ian about the grammer, rules. sorry about my bad English.

Comment: Any time! And please don't worry about it -- we can all edit questions here to help them get answers. That's really what it's all about.

Comment: With the Console app open, when you start the Time Machine backup, are there any Time Machine-related messages in Console that might shed some light on what Time Machine is doing that's keeping it in the 'preparing' state?

Comment: is there any command about for the time machine log viewing ?

Comment: than it keeping 'preparing' state http://prntscr.com/4x10l1

Comment: Do you have any relevant messages in the Console?

Comment: No there is no messages, @Buscar

Comment: Please type "backupd" in the Console sort /search window while in the all Messages selection (on the left)

Comment: right now, i created a new back up folder, on my link station. New back up operation is working. But why the oldest one, dowsnt work?

Comment: also it says command not found, http://prntscr.com/4x1fq2

Comment: With a **major** update from ML to Y, it's likely millions of files need to be checked for transfer to the time machine drive. That can take a *long* time and increase chances of failure. Under the conditions you describe, I'd consider the importance of keeping your old ML time machine files, and probably end up reformating the TM drive for a complete fresh start.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  At the Apple troubleshooting site, it stated that the initial backup after an upgrade will take a long time.  I hit "Back Up Now" before bed, and when I got up in the morning, it had completed the Back Up.  After the initial Back Up, it works just fine now!

Comment: My mac is backing up now but what was the wrong i really wonder about that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I don't know whether turning FileVault on was related (this process was suggested during Yosemite installation). However, I retried backup when FileVault finished and it worked that time.

Remember that Yosemite installation brings around new 6 GB that will be backed up. So, the preparation of backing up will delay more than usual.